# About a preacher that uses technology to deceive his audiences, leads humanity off a poisoned earth to 2 planets that forget about each other

Tags: story-identification, books

Honestly there are so many bits and pieces I can use to identify the story and Google can't find a book with any of them. This is a book I checked out of a library in London about 6 years ago so maybe it is fairly recent.

The book begins from the point of view of a shuttle pilot who is doing recon in the area around an underground city on a vulcan-type planet and finds a crashed shuttle hundreds of years old, opening with a mystery then about where the shuttle came from.

Around the same time ships arrive from a previously-unknown nearby planet and it turns out it is humans from a planet in the same solar system.

The story backtracks hundreds of years to present-day Earth and an evangelical preacher who uses technology to produce special effects in his mega-church. He becomes politically involved, and knowing that Earth is being poisoned and its days are numbered, uses his frankly pathological behavior to lead the planet to build a fleet of ships to escape the toxic earth.

The ships arrive in a far-off solar system and one crash lands on one planet (which turns out to be the vulcan-type planet from earlier), and the other lands on a forested planet. Over time the two planets lose contact and forget about each other. The preacher and his wife go into stasis, emerging every hundred years or so, to check on humanity's progress.

The preacher dude is psychopath. Dishonest, narcissistic, selfish and arrogant, except you can't argue with results. Eventually after hundreds of years, his wife rebels, creates a rebel group called The Tru (after her last name), and attempts to overthrow the theologically-controlled world he established.

It is so frustrating I can't remember this book's title. I don't even remember if it was a GOOD book, I just got an impulse to read it again.

Comment: Quick question: By "vulcan-type planet," do you mean the planet is so dry it's mostly desert, like the planet Vulcan in Star Trek?

Comment: Can you not just phone the library and ask them for your borrowing record?

Comment: Thanks guys @FuzzyBoots got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the same answer as to [Seeking a book set underground on a hostile, volcanic colony world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188563/seeking-a-book-set-underground-on-a-hostile-volcanic-colony-world), the novel "Icarus" by Roger Levy.

This description from [Publisher's Weekly](https://www.publishersweekly.com/978-0-575-07981-6):

> Initially, this impressive novel by British SF rising star Levy will
>   fascinate but also puzzle readers. The characters are immediately
>   intriguing, the writing vivid and tight, but how do the sections of
>   action fit together? What does dangerous tunneling beneath the
>   inhospitable surface of far-off planet Haven have to do with the way
>   brutal lords control villages on the forest world Haze? And what could
>   these distant civilizations have to do with a near-future
>   televangelist exploiting human weakness on Earth? However, as scene
>   follows melancholic scene, some containing disturbing violence
>   committed on or by children, cross references begin to show that the
>   parts are somehow related. Even as connections are revealed, it’s
>   never safe to relax into easy assumptions about the relationships
>   among Levy’s believably flawed, sometimes monstrous but sometimes
>   hopeful characters as they explore the pain of alienation and the
>   improbable miracle of isolated people coming together.

Comment: That's it! You got it! Thank you! I literally spent 2 hours looking for it, you're a lifesaver.

Comment: Ah right. Done!